# Getting errors while using weak symbol in C++?

Tags: c++, g++

I'm working on C++. I have created a weak symbol as follows:

```
string* myWeakSymbol(const string str)__attribute__((weak));
```

and used this symbol in a functions as follows:

```
void function()
{
   if(myWeakSymbol)
      myWeakSymbol("balaji");
}
```

When I tried to compile above code it gives an error:

```
error: could not convert 'myWeakSymbol' to 'bool'
```

Any solution to above error?

Comment: Thanks n.m. i tried tour solution but did not work.

Comment: Can't reproduce, what compiler are you using?

Comment: Sory MAt, Im using gcc version 4.1.2 20080704 (Red Hat 4.1.2-50)

Answer (score -1):

<sub>What is `if(myWeakSymbol)` supposed to do?</sub>

<sub>`myWeakSymbol` is a function. If you don't invoke `myWeakSymbol` but simply use it in an expression, it is seen as a function address. <strike>The compiler does not know how to convert a function address into a boolean value in the if statement.</strike></sub>

<sub>It has nothing to do with the weak attribute.</sub>

---

Edit: I was mistaken. You can take address of a function and put into an `if` statement. It will convert into bool. The problem must be somewhere else.

Still, it has nothing to do with the `weak` annotation.

The following example *does* compile on my machine:

```
typedef const char* string;

string* myWeakSymbol(const string str)__attribute__((weak));

void function()
{
  if(myWeakSymbol)
    myWeakSymbol("balaji");
}

int main() {
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Cygnus, but can you plz look at http://winfred-lu.blogspot.in/2009/11/understand-weak-symbols-by-examples.html describes the use of weak symbols.